# I need to detect pixel color on screen using python on Mac OS X

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, rgb

I usually program on PC so I'm pretty new to using Mac python libraries.  I would like to detect the color of a pixel at the cursors current location without clicking.  On PC, I have a something that works using the below code:

```
    pyautogui.moveTo(xcoord,ycoord,1)
    x,y=pyautogui.position()
    RGBVal=pyautogui.pixel(x,y)
```

A lot of the tools I have found when searching bring up a new hud that reads out the rgb value.  This wont work as the program will move the mouse on the screen and click based on the colors it sees so I can't have the display window on top.  The 2 leads I had that were somewhat promising were PIL where I was trying something like this:

```
    rgb = PIL.ImageGrab.grab().load()[pilx,pily]
```

The issue here is that the coordinates weren't lining up.  I tested with a pure red window and it didn't detect that it was in the square until I had the y value at ~3 times the value expected. I was assuming top left corner is 0,0 but tried with inverted y axis and things still weren't lining up properly.

The other attempt I had was using autopy.  I was originally having install issues because I was running on python version 3.10.  I have downgraded and now see Python 3.7.14 when I use python3 --version.  I was able to download and install autopy and when I try again with pip3 it shows "Requirement already satisfied" but when trying to run my code I get a "No module named 'autopy'" error at my "import autopy" line.

If anyone knows how I can make PIL or autopy work or some third option it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I managed to get pyautogui to run on the macbook but the colors were not reading true.  I also tried pyscreeze but that was reading the same values as pyautogui.  I tried connecting an external monitor and it was able to read colors properly there.  I created this question since it seems like there might not be a coding issue.
[python-unable-to-read-macbook-pro-rbg-values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74250822/python-unable-to-read-macbook-pro-rbg-values)